# Is it possible to simulate voice input using Selenium + Webdriver in end2end tests?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver

I'm trying to create a test using `Selenium + Webdriver` in Python (which runs on Chrome) to verify Voice Search by simulating voice input using `mp3` or `wav files`. I've added below `flags` to the `Chrome capabilities` but still the voice input is not being simulated.

```
--no-sandbox
--allow-file-access-from-files
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture="path-of-the-audio-file"
```

Is there a way we can simulate voice input in the E2E tests?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. you can use mp3 to convert to text using google translator jars and you can pass that text to the text box to perform a search.

Comment: Also post the code of how to convert mp3 to text.

Comment: @Nandan A : this user does not have 75+ reputation, so he wouldn't be able to comment.

Comment: @sukumar-k - Yes, but the problem is that on the UI, text appears as the user speaks (our UI is similar to that of voice search on youtube.com). There is no text box.